# "If not on front page" won't work (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, if-statement

I have this small snippet to check if

- I am on the homepage (static page set as homepage) or
- on a page which has a featured image

But it always shows me "no breadcrumb".

```
<?php if ( !has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) OR !is_front_page() OR !is_home() ) : ?>
    <p>no breadcrumb</p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I think there is a trivial error and i am just too blind to see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that you are on home page. What your condition will check if `!has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )`, means there is no post thumbnail. So it will show `<p>no breadcrumb</p>`.

Now consider you are on some other page and not home page. What your condition will check is if `!is_front_page()` or `!is_home()`. So will again show `<p>no breadcrumb</p>`.

P.S. why don't you use `||` operator instead of `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup probably should be (if it doesn't have a thumbnail and is not home or frontpage):

```
<?php if ( !has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) && !is_front_page() || !is_home() ) { ?>
    <p>no breadcrumb</p>
<?php } ?>
```

This is equates to "if it doesn't have a post thumbnail and isn't the front page or home page".

Comment: How are you referencing `$post`?

Comment: That's your problem. It probably doesn't know what `$post` is. Put `<?php global $post;?>` before it.

Comment: Doesn't work. too. postdata reset before doesn't help.

Comment: I honestly have never used code like that outside of a loop (then you don't need `$post->ID`).

Comment: This works: "if ( !has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) && !is_front_page() ) :". THX a lot anyway for your help! I think the problem was the double question ... .